# What version of GEM is required for Redmine latest?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine

I'm try to install [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Ruby-38-Ruby-on-Rails-38-Rack) . According to the installation guide, the latest(2.1.0) redmine need RubyGem <= 1.8.  What does this "***<=1.8***" mean ? Is it saying you can use any rubygem version of 1.8 serial (e.g., 1.8.23), or that only version below 1.8.0 (e.g., 1.7.0) can be used ?

Comment: Not sure what <= means, but most probably it requires a version of RubyGems greater than or equal to 1.8. Are you having problems setting it up with RubyGems >= 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a reference to those non-ruby guys like me, [this page](http://semver.org/) explains what the version number means.

Comment: Change the original link to [Semantic Versioning(SemVer)](http://semver.org/),  since RubyGem's version rule is just SemVer and the original link has some problem.

Answer (score 0):

RubyGems is a package management framework for Ruby.

This gem is an update for the RubyGems software. You must have an installation of RubyGems before this update can be applied.

Check which version you are using:`gem -v`

Update your RubyGems version:

`gem update --system`

**NOTE**: RubyGems 1.1 and 1.2 have problems upgrading when there is no rubygems-update installed. You will need to use the following instructions if you see Nothing to update. If you have an older version of RubyGems installed, then you can still do it in two steps:

> gem install rubygems-update
>
> update_rubygems